# Generalized Abel-Jacobi map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and let $\alpha:Div_{\geq0}(X)\to Pic(X)$ be the Abel-Jacobi map, where $D\mapsto\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. If $Z$ is an irreducible subvariety of $Pic(X)$ and $Y$ is an irreducible component of $\alpha^{-1}(Z)$, is it true that $Y$ is a $\mathbb{P}^n$-bundle over a subvariety of $Z$ for some $n$? In particular, is it locally trivial over its base?

Comment: $\operatorname{Pic}$ is [a scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group#Picard_scheme), but I'm not sure how you give $\operatorname{Div}_{\geq 0}$ a scheme structure?

Comment: For curves it's just the disjoint union of the symmetric products of the curve, but in general it can be defined as an open subscheme of a certain Hilbert scheme. This can be found, for example, in Fundamental Algebraic Geometry, in the chapter on the Picard scheme written by Kleiman.

Comment: why you titled "generalized Abel-Jacobi map"?

Comment: @AlexanderLau The classic Abel-Jacobi map is for curves, and I've seen the term generalized Abel-Jacobi map used for more general varieties or schemes.